# Why doesn't Safari cache this image even though Cache-Control is `public, max-age=31536000`

Tags: http, caching, safari, mobile-safari

It works fine with Chrome on macOS, but not with Safari + macOS (or iOS)

Age: 2366102
Expires: Fri, 16 Feb 2024 11:05:21 GMT
Cache-Control: public,max-age=31536000,immutable

https://meo.comick.pictures/YKm6O.jpg

[image]

Comment: Safari 16.3 (18614.4.6.1.5) on macOS 13.2 (22D49) seems to consistently do the right thing - load via network if I force it, load from memory cache if I return in the same session, load from disk cache if I return after closing the browser.

Comment: can we see the full headers of the response and the request?

Comment: @ricardkelly https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xhc_N4GA-J4 This is my recorded video.

Answer (score 0):

I'm observing similar behavior for JavaScript files on both localhost and my production site.

After some experimentation, the problem seems to be a `crossorigin` on a Link modulepreload:

```html
<link rel="modulepreload" crossorigin href="/assets/_commonjsHelpers-042e6b4d.js">
```

If I remove the link `crossorigin` attribute, Safari uses the cache for JS files.

Details: Safari Version 16.2 (18614.3.7.1.5) on macOS laptop.

[image: Detail with cache-control]